# Symfony2 - apply attribute to radio buttons

Tags: forms, symfony, radio-button, formbuilder

I want to add an attribute to a radio-button form input. I want to add jquery validation to them. When I specify the attr in the form_widget function in twig, the attributes are applied to the div where the input elements are in.

How do I apply the attributes to the input element?

Comment: In your case, the best way could be to edit form theme. You can check the documentation about this topic: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming